# Textbox multiple line and blank line disappear

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, textbox

I have a Winform application built with C# and .Net 2.0. I have a textbox set with the MultiLine property.

The problem is when someone writes text with multiple lines (press few enters), presses the save button, and then closes and loads the form again, all the new lines disappear (the text is there at least).

For example, if the textbox had this in it:

```
Line1

Line3
```

It will look like this after I save and load:

```
Line1 Line3
```

Any idea why?

**Update**

The database is PostGres and when I use PGAdmin I can see all the line AND the "enters". So the persistence seem to have save all the line... the problem seem to be when I put back the string in the Textbox.

Comment: What happens in your "save" button's event handler?

Comment: Save button go save the textbox1.Text to the database. The problem is when I load it back to the form, I do not see any line

Comment: What database are you using and what type of field?

Comment: I have put some more information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the textbox is really a string array.

I think you can do this:

```
textBox1.Lines = foo.Split(new String[] {"\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit again: If you want to keep the blank lines, the change to StringSplitOptions.None

Answer (score 0):

In Windows forms all carriage returns are preserved in a multiline text box, so the problem likely lies in the way data is retrieved from your database. I've never used PostGres, but I'm guessing that the way you're retrieving the text from the db is replacing all whitespace with single spaces.